# draw all shapes in a stage KineticJS

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am putting two layers in a stage. The first layer has only a rectangle. The other layer has several line objects. I need to draw these lines very fast so I'm trying to draw all the lines at once, but I couldn't make it work. Here is my code:

```
var line = new Kinetic.Line({
                points : line_points,
                stroke : 'black',
                strokeWidth : 5,
                lineCap : 'round'
            });
            layer.add(line);
            layer.draw();
        });

    };

});

stage.add(layer);
```

This code draws all lines separately after being created, so it takes a little bit more time. How can I draw all of the lines at once?

---

here is the rest of my function :

```
function draw_ways(db, minLon, maxLon, minLat, maxLat, stage) {

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

get_interval_ways(db, minLon, maxLon, minLat, maxLat, function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        get_interval_nodes(db, result[i].way_id, function(result2) {
            var line_points = new Array();
            for (var j = 0; j < result2.length; j++) {
                line_points.push(getLocationX(result2[j].lon, minLon, maxLon, MAP_WIDTH));
                line_points.push(getLocationY(result2[j].lat, minLat, maxLat, MAP_HEIGHT));
            };

            var line = new Kinetic.Line({
                points : line_points,
                stroke : 'black',
                strokeWidth : 5,
                lineCap : 'round'
            });
            layer.add(line);
            layer.draw();
        });
    };
});
stage.add(layer);
console.log(stage);
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to draw them with your mouse? Or just programatically?

Comment: Just programatically.I call this function directly inside .html file.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your nested code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw multiple lines in a for loop you need to use an array like this:

```
var line = [];
var line_count = 5;
for (var i=0; i<line_count; i++) {
  line[i] = new Kinetic.Line({
    points : line_points,
    stroke : 'black',
    strokeWidth : 5,
    lineCap : 'round'
  });
  layer.add(line[i]);
}
layer.draw(); //We only need to draw the layer once, so put it outside the for-loop
```

*After all the lines have been added to the layer, you can draw the entire layer once and they will all be drawn onto the layer together.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/zAjHj/)

Comment: Actually if i called draw method outside the the first loop,code would make the same thing.But when i call draw after adding all the lines it didn't worked.That may be because of my asynchoronious functions.Isn't there anyway to drawing the stage?Stage contains all lines in a layer.

Comment: You can use stage.draw(), but I don't think that will solve your problem. What do you mean "code would make the same thing" ? Did you try using an array like I did for the **line** variable?

Comment: There is no difference between adding a line object and adding an element of line array.I tried to add all the lines without drawing seperately.After that i tried to draw stage or layer.but it did not work.

Comment: Use console.log(layer.getChildren()) to see if the lines are even being added to the layer (which they should be). Another thing to check is if your line_points has the right amount of points. For a 2 point line you need 4 values [x1, y1, x2, y2]. If you only specify 2 points, you're drawing a single dot (x,y) coordinate, in which Kinetic won't even render anything for that.

Comment: Yep,i checked it.Everything seems right.I have 99 lines in my layer.Each one has x,y coordinates in attribute points..

Comment: yep.it seems object array.Each object has x and y coordinates.

Comment: Double check and see if the line: **stage.add(layer)** is adding the right layer that has the lines added to it. Now what I'm suspecting because of the structure of your code (nested functions), is that you might be **adding an empty layer** to the stage. Use console.log(stage); to see if it has the newest added layer as a child, and then check that layer to see if it has **all** the new children (all the lines). I realised that when you add a new layer to the stage, all nodes that are already added to the layer beforehand are automatically drawn when the layer is added to the stage.